# The app keeps stopping, what should i do?

Tags: crash

I started programming with Android Studio a week ago and wanted to code an alarm clock
my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TimePicker picker= (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    TextClock txtClock= (TextClock) findViewById(R.id.txtClock);
    Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    TextView txt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Ringtone r= RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM));
    picker.setIs24HourView(false);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int hour,minute;
            hour=picker.getHour();
            minute=picker.getMinute();
            if (txtClock.getText().toString().equals(hour+":"+minute))
            {
                r.play();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

i´m still not finished but it was supposed to work like this

what did i do wrong?

my error code:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mathe_wecker, PID: 19447
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

```
******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5851)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5772)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1661)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzee.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@21.3.0:20)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@21.3.0:1)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6285)
        ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0):

check your app/build.gradle and comment this

```
implementation com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads
```

It require initialisation setup in your manifest file which are briefly available [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk)

I was waiting for Google AdMob key so setup won't be possible without that, as a temporary solution I comment out that implementation.